# How can an upvote be undone after 15 minutes without the post change?

Tags: support, bug

I posted this question [A question involving dead cats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117138/a-question-involving-dead-cats) several months ago, and it received one upvote around that time.

It was last edited several months ago, and any vote should be locked in after 5 minutes after the vote was cast, unless the post is edited.

So the upvote shouldn't be able to be undone, and yet recently it was unupvoted.

I don't care about the reputation loss, I am just curious, how can this happen? Did someone hack the system?

Comment: *"...unless the post is edited"*. So the post has been edited.

Comment: No, I think the post was not edited after the vote was cast.

Comment: Once you hit 1k rep, you will be able to see [vote counts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user). Currently the linked post stands at +1/-2. (Previously +2/-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133297) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com):

> 1. Since you edited your post shortly after posting, someone could have upvoted within that initial 17 minute window, and decided to undo it later.
> 2. <s>If someone with edit privileges really wants to undo their own locked vote, they can edit the post themselves, undo their vote, and then undo their edit. If this is done within the editing grace period, their edit disappears forever.</s> [This is no longer possible.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180564) (Note that the original post is more than 10 years old.)

According to your reputation history, two upvotes were cast on *Jul 18, 2022 at 5:43* and on *Jul 19, 2022 at 18:13*. And your post has been edited on *Jul 18, 2022 at 6:17*. Therefore it is possible to retract the first upvote. <s>The second scenerio mentioned above is also possible.</s>

So it's not a bug and no one has hacked the system.